# Did boost::optional's implicit cast to bool go away?

Tags: c++, boost, option-type

I started porting a vc++10/boost 1.48 codebase to vc++12/boost 1.57 and I'm getting an error that boost::optional can't convert to bool. I thought this was a feature of boost::optional, did it get removed?

Example:

```
bool fizz(){
  boost::optional<int32_t> buzz;
  return buzz;
}
```

gives

```
Error   21  error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'boost::optional<int32_t>' to 'bool'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. [Boost 1.55](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp) still used the [Safe Bool Idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool):

```
// implicit conversion to "bool"
// No-throw
operator unspecified_bool_type() const { return this->safe_bool() ; }
```

[Boost 1.56](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp), [Boost 1.57](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp) and [Boost 1.58](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp) now use this macro:

```
BOOST_EXPLICIT_OPERATOR_BOOL_NOEXCEPT()
```

which is roughly:

```
#if !defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_EXPLICIT_CONVERSION_OPERATORS)
    explicit operator bool() const noexcept;
#else if !defined(BOOST_NO_UNSPECIFIED_BOOL)
    operator boost::detail::unspecified_bool_type () const noexcept;
#else
    operator bool () const noexcept;
#endif
```

I'm guessing you don't have `BOOST_NO_CXX11_EXPLICIT_CONVERSION_OPERATORS` defined - and since your compiler supports explicit conversion operators, you should probably keep it that way!

Comment: 1.58's implementation didn't change. It still uses the macro.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Letting me know about the macro is very useful as we have to support the old stuff for another half year or so.

Comment: You can return !!buzz;

Comment: @BenPope You can. Or you could just... explicitly cast it to `bool`, which would be much more understandable to everyone.